# When will ruby's ensure not run?

Tags: ruby, exception

I have a server running in an eventmachine reactor which listens to heartbeats from users to tell if they are online. It marks the users as online and offline appropriately, when it starts/stops receiving the heartbeat.

I want to wrap it all in an ensure block to mark all currently online users offline when it exits, but I'm unsure how reliable that would be.

Under what conditions could a process exit without running the ensure blocks wrapping the current execution context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few, for example:

- being killed with kill -9
- segmentation faults etc (eg bugs in ruby itself or in native extensions)
- power failures
- the system as a whole crashing (eg kernel/driver bugs, hardware failures etc)

A network failure wouldn't stop your ensure block from running but might mean that it can't update whatever datastore stores these statuses.